# Simple Compass+HAML webserver

Tags: ruby, haml, sass, compass-sass, staticmatic

I love compass (SASS) and HAML. I've been using staticmatic for building static web pages. Staticmatic seams outdated (no updates, bugs). What are the alternatives?

What I would like:

```
$ preview .
> Server started ad port XXXX
> Now you can use Compass and HAML
```

:). So... no configuratio, no directory structure, just haml and sass files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently using Compass/Sass/Haml with middleman.  https://github.com/tdreyno/middleman  It is very easy to use, and runs a sinatra in the background so you can see your changes live in your web browser.

After you are done editing and previewing your markup it builds static HTML from your stack of Compass/Sass/Haml.  See https://github.com/tdreyno/middleman/wiki for usage.

This requires no conf at all except to tell it which templating engines you are using at setup so I think it is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes... I tried that. Like it but still... it requires directory structure.

Comment: Well it requires a directory for your sass, and a directory for your haml but I do not see how anyone could do this without some directory structure as it is generating static HTML that has to bring in assets like stylesheets/images etc.

Comment: guys, the https://github.com/tdreyno/middleman/wiki is dead. Any other link to get instructions to setup for Sass/Compass/Haml to convert to appropriate files?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). I think it doesn't work with `sass` and `haml` out of the box but you can look at [plugins](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget [Nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/). While it is a little involved, it has some slightly more powerful features than StaticMatic. It does depend on a directory however. :/

Answer (score 0):

There are just a ton of static generators around, most of them in Ruby. I'm planning to use [Frank](https://github.com/blahed/frank) for the next few static projects.

- It uses [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) to support a ton of template engines
- It has a concept of layouts, which go in a separate layouts folder, and templates can have a metadata header, but other than that it's very minimal.